# How to remove both positive and negative duplicates from panda dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a retail sales data and would like to delete both duplicated values ie. the returns (which are mentioned as negatives values in Quantity column) and corresponding purchases using Quantity as a reference.
Using drop_duplicate function removes one of those duplicates, where I would like to delete both entries.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). An image can't be considered as a sample.

Comment: @CuriousMonkey keep=False